# Moving chart to top of pop-up window in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, graph, chart

Is it possible to move a chart/graph to the top of the pop-up window in ArcGIS Online via its GUI?

I have numerous fields to display and it works best if the chart is displayed first.

Just the standard chart that the web map provides now would suffice.

Having to modify HTML code seems a little much for functionality that seems fairly basic.

Answer (score 1):

More specific details as to what you are wanting to accomplish, such as how the chart should look, would help us answer this better.

Having said that, you can modify the pop-up window more by selecting "a custom attribute display" in the pulldown in the "Configure Pop-up" menu.  When you choose this option you are able to edit the html code of the pop-up window which would include creating a chart and placing it at the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your chart to AGOL, grab the direct URL Link for it (bottom of page).
Create a new field in your attribute table (for your chart) and paste the direct url into it.

when configuring the pop-up use the chart field name {chartfield} add that first then the rest of the data you want in the pop-up.

Comment: The chart is not uploaded, it's using the widget in the AGOL configure popup to create (pop-up media). Can the chart be moved when created this way?

Comment: I do not believe so, however if it is the same chart just create an image file for it (or unique image for different charts) and upload it. Should work fine. Not ideal but it will work

Comment: It is a different chart for each polygon.

Comment: How many Polygons are we talking about here? Just upload a new unique img url for new table field. if its a large number of polygons then maybe someone else has a better option

Comment: There are about 70 polygons; too many to create an image for each.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use the chart widget in the application? http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-chart.htm

Comment: I was referring to the possibility of moving it in the web map before any app gets created. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are using the pop-up configuration to add charts then no. it will be forced at the bottom of the pop-up window.

Comment: ESRI really needs to improve this basic functionality.